# New sub-theme not showing in appearance

Tags: theming

I am working with Drupal's Open social framework where in I copy socialblue theme so that i can do my modifications in the new theme. I followed the below steps, cleared cache, yet I am not able to see my new theme in admin/appearance section.

Steps I followed:

1) I duplicated the theme socialblue (html/profiles/contrib/social/themes/socialblue) to newtheme (html/profiles/contrib/social/themes/newtheme)

2) I did a search (socialblue) and replace (newtheme) inside of “newtheme” directory

3) I changed the names of the following files from “socialblue” to “newtheme"

```
newtheme.info.yml
newtheme.libraries.yml
newtheme.theme
config/install/newtheme.settings.yml
```

4) I created a /html/sites/default/services.yml file from default.services.yml and made the following changes

```
twig.config -> debug: true
twig.config -> auto_reload: true
twig.config -> cache: false
```

5) html/profiles/contrib/social/themes/newtheme$ yarn install

6) html/profiles/contrib/social/themes/newtheme$ sudo npm install -g gulp-cli

7) html/profiles/contrib/social/themes/newtheme$ gulp

I do not get any error. I made sure that my newtheme.info file has name newtheme. I also copied this new theme in html/themes/custom/newtheme still no luck. Am I missing something?

Comment: You may need to put your theme in the proper theme directory - `html/themes/custom/newtheme` - and not in the install profile directory. And then clear the cache https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/prevent-cache-clear.html

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. Turns out it was because my base theme was mentioned as 'socialblue'. I changed it to 'socialbase' and it worked out. I don't know if a parent theme can have more than one child themes in drupal 8.